# How to get Unbounce sitemap submitted to Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

We have created few landing pages with Unbounce as subdomains to our website. However, Search Console shows no data in Search Traffic or any other.

It does not allow us to submit a sitemap as these are one pagers, and Unbounce forums say that they do not have a function to submit .xml to Webmaster Tools. And Unbounce goal is not Organic search but leads and conversions.

Google Analytics says that traffic to those LPs come Directly or through Referral. (Which I think is a bit odd)

We want to optimize the website for the keywords that users use to land on those pages, and would very much like to get to that information in Search Console (specifically Search Analytics).

Any suggestions how to work around this Unbounce stance for no-organic search results and no .xml?

(Tried third party .xml generators, but did not work. All it said for /sitemap.xml : The requested URL was not found on this server.)

Comment: Sitemaps do nothing for you. If you are thinking there is a search performance advantage to having a sitemap, I assure you this is **not** the case. Any advice to submit a sitemap is often a false one. Why? Because if a search engine can properly crawl your site, and being one page I am sure there is no issue there, then there is no reason to have a sitemap. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbounce is right, landing pages are not for SEO.   Landing pages tend to be heavy on marketing messaging with a clear call to action.   SEO pages need to have less marketing, more content, and more utility to users.

The Google Analytics report is probably right.   When you run marketing campaigns to landing page, the traffic will show up as direct or referral (from ads).   You can fix that issue by tagging your ad URLs with [UTM parameters](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/).  Then the traffic will show up as mostly campaign traffic.

To see search analytics you would have to add these subdomains to Google Search Console as separate sites.   You could probably get them validated through DNS or Google Analytics, but it sounds like Unbounce probably doesn't support meta tag or file upload validation.   Once you have them added though, you will probably find that there is no data.  Google shouldn't be sending organic traffic to your landing pages.   You shouldn't be trying to optimize your landing page for organic keywords.

Sitemaps are not going to help you here.   They don't help rankings.   They won't get Google to index pages with little value to searchers.